# How to enable digits only in pytesser?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I'm running pytesser to OCR an image in python. The first time I screengrab an image off the page, it's fine, but the accuracy worsens in the next few pages, until 87+1 is $+$

Odd, eh? My guess is that because pytesser(port from tesseract for python) is built to recognize words, and puts what you OCR into context for the next question. So, with no way to disable this, i can only set it to digits only right? But pytesser doesn't have much documentation on it, so i went on to the tesseract faq, but I don't really get the code.

> Use
>
> ```
> TessBaseAPI::SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
> ```
>
> BEFORE calling an Init function or put this in a text file called
>   `tessdata/configs/digits`:
>
> ```
> tessedit_char_whitelist 0123456789
> ```
>
> and then your command line becomes:
>
> ```
> tesseract image.tif outputbase nobatch digits
> ```
>
> Warning: Until the old and new config variables get merged, you must
>   have the nobatch parameter too.

I'm guessing tat's for C or C++. Is there any way to do this in python? Or even better, disable context for the OCR?

Answer (score 1):

In python:

```
import tesseract
ocr = tesseract.TessBaseAPI();
ocr.Init(".","eng",tesseract.OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY)
ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789")
```

you might also want:

```
ocr.SetVariable("classify_enable_learning", "0")
ocr.SetVariable("classify_enable_adaptive_matcher", "0")
```